# Class and genric object both implementing interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a class which uses generic objects. Generic object needs to implement IDisposable interface. Class also needs to implement IDisposable.

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> where T : IDisposable
```

Now in this Generic object implements interface, but class doesn't. Is it possible that both implement interface? If yes the how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> : IDisposable
    where T : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying MyGenericClass<T> : IDisposable : where T : IDisposable. Thanks for the answer,

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible:

> public class MyGenericClass: IDisposable where T : IDisposable